# How do I turn off Rails SQL logging in test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, logging, ruby-on-rails-4

For some reason (probably an updated gem) Rails is logging all my SQL commands now. I run autotest and they are being spammed during tests also. How do I turn it off?

I tried add this to config/environments/test.rb but it didn't work. `logger` was already `nil`.

```
# ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil
# ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 1
```

Rails 4.0.0

Comment: Run `grep -r 'config.logger' .` in your project and see what it's set to.

Comment: This was the only result: `config/environments/production.rb:  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok I found it. This worked:

```
config.after_initialize do
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil
end
```

Comment: This is awesome to limit ALL logging, but I only want to limit the SQL logging, similar to categories in LOG4J? I also use trace/debug logging, and do not want to switch that off. Is that at all possible with Rails logging, or do I have to use LOG4R, to get that kind of granular logging?

Comment: @alwynd `ActiveRecord` only logs SQL. The other logging is unaffected by this. See if something else is turning it off.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you can do is call this code at runtime, it doesn't need to be in a config file.

For example, if you put in your specific test case

```
# test/functionals/application_controller_test.rb for example
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil
```

It would work just as well, and this way you can toggle it at runtime. Useful if you only want to stifle a few lines of code or a block.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone wants to **actually** knock out SQL statement logging (without changing logging level, and while keeping the logging from their AR models):

The line that writes to the log (in Rails 3.2.16, anyway) is the call to 'debug' in lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:50.

That debug method is defined by ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.

So we can knock out the logging by overwriting it like so:

```
module ActiveSupport
  class LogSubscriber
    def debug(*args, &block)
    end
  end
end
```